# How to auto run commands when log on to Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 running within WSL 2 on a Windows 10 computer.

Every time I login to Ubuntu, I had to manually execute these four line by pasting it one by one in the Windows 10 Terminal.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -yqq daemonize dbus-user-session fontconfig

sudo daemonize /usr/bin/unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target

exec sudo nsenter -t $(pidof systemd) -a su - $LOGNAME

sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start
```

May I know if there is a way to skip this manual process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .bashrc file to execute commands whenever you open the terminal. It should be located at $HOME directory.

```
cd $HOME
nano .bashrc
```

place your commands at the end of the file, press ctl+x then y to save.